# Is it valid to use unsupervised clustering to assign patients into larger groups before comparing them to controls?

Tags: clustering, multiple-comparisons, group-differences, k-nearest-neighbour, case-control-study

I have very high-dimensional data (lipidomics) with two categories: patient/control and genetic mutation. These mutations have similar phenotypes, but they are considered different diseases. Their effect on the lipidome isn't entirely understood, so I don't think I can assign patient groups based on domain knowledge only.

I want to know if I can legitimately do something like using k-means only on the patients and then comparing the resulting groups to controls instead of having to test each specific mutation against the controls or having to treat all patients as one group and the controls as another.

Comment: So you have a control group and another group which is possibly composed of two subgroups, but you do not know the subgroups? So you wish to use clustering to determine the subgroups and then compare these to the control group?

Comment: @user2974951 yeah, I guess that's it exactly

Comment: How many patients do you have in the "genetic mutation" group?

Comment: You could do that, but the result could be nonsense, it really depends what clustering will capture. It might capture just what you are interested in (these two specific diseases) or it might cluster something completely irrelevant to you and the comparison will then be useless.

Comment: @dipetkov There's 10 mutations, some are unique and a couple have like 10 patients each

Comment: @user2974951 Sorry it's not just two diseases, there's about 10. Do you think it makes more sence to keep them separate?

Comment: @user2974951 Or maybe I could try two-factor ANOVA to see if the mutation matters more than patient/control?

Comment: Personally I don't see how k-means would give you interpretable and meaningful clusters that are relevant to the problem at hand. (I think that's true for all non-textbooks problems). The fact that "genetic mutation" is a catch-all for 10 mutations only makes this more challenging. Anyway, this is relevant information that should be included in the question.

Comment: Please include new information as an edit to the post, and not only in comments! We want posts on this site to be self-contained, and commentsare often only seen by a few people, and can be deleted ...